# Load Distribution not working in Kubernetes, Request is going to single pod

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

**I m using Minikube for kubernetes deployment and Operating system i m using is Ubuntu 18.04**

*I have a Deployment of my application with 3 replicas. So when i deploy 3 pods gets deployed .
when i increase the number of http request all the request are forwarded to the a single pod while there are no logs recorded in the other two replicas.*

Any ideas on how the load get distributed across all the pods.

i have the deployment.yaml and respective service.yaml file below

```
    deployment.yaml


    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
          name: master
      labels:
       app: master-container
    spec:
     selector:
       matchLabels:
         app: master-container
     replicas: 3
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           app: master-container
       spec:
         volumes:
         - name: logs-dir
           hostPath:
            path: /data/logs/
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
         containers:
          - name: master-container
            image: image:1
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/workspace/logs/
              name: logs-dir

    service.yaml
    
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: master-container
  labels:
    app: master-container
spec:
  selector:
    app: master-container
  ports:
  - port: 2000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2000
    name: can-port
    nodePort: 32000
  - port: 2002
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2002
    name: can-ajp-port
    nodePort: 32002
  - port: 2003
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2003
    name: cas-port
    nodePort: 32003
  - port: 2005
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 2005
    name: cas-ajp-port
    nodePort: 32005
  - port: 31900
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31900
    name: cas-master-port
    nodePort: 31900
  type: NodePort
```

Have a look at the below image this is the output of the command

kubectl describe svc canmastercontainer

We can see that service is up and all the ports are accessible . The only issue i m facing is that the load distribution is not happening across the pods

[image]

i have tried giving type as NodePort , LoadBalancer and ClusterIp all the three didnt work out .
All the http request are getting transferred to the single pod .

Any solutions would be appriciated thank you

Comment: Did you verify all pods selected are working fine?

Comment: Could you provide informations from one test scenario? Your manifests including `app: master-container` but in the screen selector and label is `app: canmasterconainer`. Also type is different between screen and manifests. Are you used helm to deploy this app (saw Helm annotations), if so can you share chart? Did you consider using [Nginx Ingress Patch Matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/)?  Can you see any issues in pods logs?

Comment: @slashpai   All the pods are working fine and there are no issues in the pod logs . The only issue here is whenever i make a request from the browser  the request transferred to a single pod , while there are no logs generated in the other two pods .

Comment: @PjoterS : All the selector matching  in my  deployment and all the pods are running.  For the helm part i m using helm for deployment and the above files is what i have been using for the deployment . The issue i m facing here is there is no Load Distribution happening b/w the pods even when i have multiple replicas of the pod. when i make a http request from the browser all the request gets transferred to a single pod  while the other replicas of the pod remain idle i,e the request is not hitting those pods . i would like to know how the load distribution works .

Comment: Could you ensure that `kube-proxy` put proper rules to `iptables`? Also check if `iptables rules works as expected?
Did you consider using Ingress?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using port forwarding then the load will not be distributed across all pods (endpoints).

Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925781/load-distribution-all-http-requests-are-getting-redirected-to-a-single-pod-in-a/64927127#64927127) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Every node in a Kubernetes cluster runs a `kube-proxy`. `kube-proxy` is responsible for implementing a form of `virtual IP` for `Services` of type other than `ExternalName`.

`kube-proxy` can work in a few modes:

- [User space proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace)
- [iptables proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-iptables)
- [IPVS proxy mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-ipvs)

However, expect built-in Kubernetes methods you can use 3rd party software like [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

#### Test scenario

Nginx Ingress, bare metal consideration on GCP Ubuntu VM.

**Hello world YAML**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      key: application-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        key: application-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello1
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**Service Yaml:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-one
spec:
  selector:
    key: application-1
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

**Ingress Yaml:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"      
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /one
        backend:
          serviceName: service-one
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /two
        backend:
          serviceName: service-two
          servicePort: 80
```

**Ingress Description:**

```
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           
              /one   service-one:80 (192.168.243.80:8080,192.168.243.84:8080,192.168.243.85:8080)
              /two   service-two:80 (192.168.243.81:8080,192.168.243.82:8080,192.168.243.83:8080)
```

#### Tests

```
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/one
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-4x4pd
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/one
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-vq72x
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/one
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-1-77ddb77d56-v5826
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/one
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-xk5h9
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-lw74g
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-xk5h9
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-lw74g
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-8pfls
$ curl 34.89.244.41:31337/two
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: deployment-2-fb984955c-8pfls
```

As you can see, each request was redirected to different pod.

If this won't work, please provide more details which was asked under your question.