# Load distribution: All HTTP requests are getting redirected to a single pod in a k8 cluster

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube, kubernetes-pod, kube-proxy

I have created a very simple spring boot application with only one REST service. This app is converted into a docker image ("springdockerimage:1") and deployed in the Kubernetes cluster with 3 replicas. Contents of my "Deployment" definition is as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: springapp
  labels:
   app: distributiondemo
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: distributiondemo
 replicas: 3
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: distributiondemo
   spec:
     containers:
      - name: spring-container
        image: springdockerimage:1
```

I have created service for my above deployment as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: springservice
  labels:
    app: distributiondemo
spec:
  selector:
    app: distributiondemo
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
    name: spring-port
    nodePort: 32000
  type: NodePort
```

After deploying both the above YAML(deployment and service) files, I noticed that everything has been deployed as expected i.e., 3 replicas are created and my service is having 3 endpoints as well. Below screenshot is the proof of the same:
[image]

Since I am using minikube for my local testing, I am port forwarding and accessing the application as **kubectl port-forward deployment.apps/springapp 40002:8080** .

But one thing I noticed is that all my HTTP requests are getting redirected to only one pod.

```
while true ; do curl http://localhost:40002/docker-java-app/test ;done
```

I am not getting where exactly I am doing it wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loadbalancing might not work with port-forwarded ports as it might be directly redirecting traffic to pod (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59940833/does-kubectl-port-forward-ignore-loadbalance-services)). The K8s service is the feature will give you that loadbalancing capability.

So you can try either of below instead

1. Use `http://your_service_dns_name:8080/docker-java-app/test`
2. Use `http://service_cluster_ip:8080/docker-java-app/test`
3. Use `http://any_host_ip_from_k8s_cluster:32000/docker-java-app/test`

Option 1 and 2 works only if you are accessing those urls from a host which is part of K8s cluster. Option 3 just needs connectivity to target host and port, from the host you are accessing url.